# Suppress in CrystalReport if a Database Filed(i.e ImageData) is not present

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

I want to suppress the ImageField in which is sub field of a database field.
Database field "Receipt" contains three sub fields in which one is Image data.

I am trying to suppress the field when there is no image data. please help me with a formula that should be written after checking the suppress checkbox.

Comment: what do you mean by 'subfield'? Are there in Receipt field some comma separated values that act as 'subfields'? (ie. `Receipt = "abc,123,def"`)

Comment: What do you mean by sub field